# CSS images vanishing on refresh

Tags: html, image, css, coda

I have some very basic HTML and CSS and it's got to the point now where I'm sure my code is fine (or at least to my eyes), and the images load in their respective fields. But as soon as I hit refresh they vanish.

I'm using Coda 2 which uses the Safari browser for a preview. All of my code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Input Images</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/input-image.css" />
</head>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="email" />
        <input type="text" id="twitter" />
        <input type="text" id="web" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
input {
    font-size: 120%;
    color: #5a5854;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 8px 9px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;}

input:focus, input:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #b1e1e4;}
input#email {
    background-image: url("images/email.png");}
input#twitter {
    background-image: url("images/twitter.png");}
input#web {
    background-image: url("images/web.png");}
```

Comment: It must be some issue with the ide, try using absolute paths for your urls: `"/images/email.png"`.

Comment: Such a pain but it worked. Is this just a IDE issue then as it seems very odd. Thanks for the pointer though.

Comment: I posted it as an answer, please accept it if it was useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be some issue on how the IDE handle assets paths.

Using absolute paths (which is the right way) should work: `url("/images/email.png")`.

Comment: This is relative path, isn't it?

Comment: No, the first slash in the path means it's absolute, and unrelated to where it's being required from

Comment: That's a root-relative path and not an absolute path.

Comment: Right, and since root is "the root" it makes that an absolute path ;) but I got what you mean